# Making qgis2web search engine to search multiple columns rather than just one column?

Tags: javascript, leaflet, qgis

I have created a map using Leaflet and QGIS2Web. The search engine works fine, however it looks through only one of column of the attribute table. My goal is to have it search through four different columns (Country, division, subdivision, language) rather than just one (language). For that, I want to create a custom data array from layer features when loading the layer, which will contain four array items for each feature. The new array will then be used as the source data (using sourceData option) for the search engine. The only issue remaining is that if the user searches for a language that is spoken at various locations in Africa, how can I have the map show all the locations that speak the language searched for?

Code sample that I will be using to create a custom data array:

```js
var data = [
        {"loc":[41.575330,13.102411], "title":"aquamarine"},
        {"loc":[41.575730,13.002411], "title":"black"},
        {"loc":[41.807149,13.162994], "title":"blue"},
        {"loc":[41.507149,13.172994], "title":"chocolate"},
        {"loc":[41.847149,14.132994], "title":"coral"},
        {"loc":[41.219190,13.062145], "title":"cyan"},
        {"loc":[41.344190,13.242145], "title":"darkblue"},  
        {"loc":[41.679190,13.122145], "title":"darkred"},
        {"loc":[41.329190,13.192145], "title":"darkgray"},
        {"loc":[41.379290,13.122545], "title":"dodgerblue"},
        {"loc":[41.409190,13.362145], "title":"gray"},
        {"loc":[41.794008,12.583884], "title":"green"}, 
        {"loc":[41.805008,12.982884], "title":"greenyellow"},
        {"loc":[41.536175,13.273590], "title":"red"},
        {"loc":[41.516175,13.373590], "title":"rosybrown"},
        {"loc":[41.506175,13.173590], "title":"royalblue"},
        {"loc":[41.836175,13.673590], "title":"salmon"},
        {"loc":[41.796175,13.570590], "title":"seagreen"},
        {"loc":[41.436175,13.573590], "title":"seashell"},
        {"loc":[41.336175,13.973590], "title":"silver"},
        {"loc":[41.236175,13.273590], "title":"skyblue"},
        {"loc":[41.546175,13.473590], "title":"yellow"},
        {"loc":[41.239190,13.032145], "title":"white"}
    ];

    var map = new L.Map('map', {zoom: 9, center: new L.latLng(data[0].loc) });

    map.addLayer(new L.TileLayer('https://{s}.tile.openstreetmap.org/{z}/{x}/{y}.png'));    //base layer

    function localData(text, callResponse)
    {
        //here can use custom criteria or merge data from multiple layers

        callResponse(data);

        return {    //called to stop previous requests on map move
            abort: function() {
                console.log('aborted request:'+ text);
            }
        };
    }
```

Below is the JavaScript code showing the fields I export:

```js
<tr>\
                        <th scope="row">Language</th>\
                        <td>' + (!!feature.properties['q2wHide_lang2'] ? autolinker.link(feature.properties['q2wHide_lang2'].toLocaleString()) : '') + '</td>\
                    </tr>\
                    <tr>\
                        <th scope="row">State</th>\
                        <td>' + (!!feature.properties['State'] ? autolinker.link(feature.properties['State'].toLocaleString()) : '') + '</td>\
                    </tr>\
                    <tr>\
                        <th scope="row">Local Gove</th>\
                        <td>' + (!!feature.properties['Local Gove'] ? autolinker.link(feature.properties['Local Gove'].toLocaleString()) : '') + '</td>\
                    </tr>\
                    <tr>\
                        <th scope="row">Country</th>\
                        <td>' + (!!feature.properties['Country'] ? autolinker.link(feature.properties['Country'].toLocaleString()) : '') + '</td>\
                    </tr>\
                </table>';
```

Below is the code for the search box:

```js
setBounds();
        map.addControl(new L.Control.Search({
            layer: layer_Eth_Region_2013_Project_Merg_1,
            initial: false,
            hideMarkerOnCollapse: true,
            propertyName: 'q2wHide_lang2'}));
        document.getElementsByClassName('search-button')[0].className +=
         ' fa fa-binoculars';
        var mapDiv = document.getElementById('map');
```

I have checked online and have found similar issues but not exactly the same. The solution for those were concatenation, however I am not if this is a correct solution for me. I appreciate any help.

Answer (score 0):

Have you thought about creating a fifth column by adding the data of the four columns into it?
Just use the QGIS field calculator to do it in a single command.
Then do the qgis2web setup in this fifth column.
This way when your users start typing the language they will see the different locations in the drop-down menu that they can select for zooming.
Greetings.